# Go into every subdirectory and mass rename files by stripping leading characters

Tags: bash, file, find, rename

From the current directory I have multiple sub directories:

```
subdir1/
 001myfile001A.txt
 002myfile002A.txt
subdir2/
 001myfile001B.txt
 002myfile002B.txt
```

where I want to strip every character from the filenames before `myfile` so I end up with

```
subdir1/
 myfile001A.txt
 myfile002A.txt
subdir2/
 myfile001B.txt
 myfile002B.txt
```

I have some code to do this...

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in `find . -type d -maxdepth 1`; do
   cd "$d"
   for f in `find . "*.txt"`; do
        mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed -r 's/^.*myfile/myfile/')"
   done

done
```

however the newly renamed files end up in the parent directory

i.e.

```
 myfile001A.txt
 myfile002A.txt
 myfile001B.txt
 myfile002B.txt
 subdir1/
 subdir2/
```

In which the sub-directories are now empty.

How do I alter my script to rename the files and keep them in their respective sub-directories? As you can see the first loop changes directory to the sub directory so not sure why the files end up getting sent up a directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has multiple problems.  In the first place, your outer `find` command doesn't do quite what you expect: it outputs not only each of the subdirectories, but also the search root, `.`, which is itself a directory.  You could have discovered this by running the command manually, among other ways.  You don't really need to use `find` for this, but supposing that you *do* use it, this would be better:

```
for d in $(find * -maxdepth 0 -type d); do
```

Moreover, `.` is the *first* result of your original `find` command, and your problems continue there.  Your initial `cd` is without meaningful effect, because you're just changing to the same directory you're already in.  The `find` command in the inner loop is rooted there, and descends into both subdirectories.  The path information for each file you choose to rename is therefore stripped by `sed`, which is why the results end up in the initial working directory (`./subdir1/001myfile001A.txt` --> `myfile001A.txt`). By the time you process the subdirectories, there are no files left in them to rename.

But that's not all: the `find` command in your inner loop is incorrect.  Because you do not specify an option before it, `find` interprets `"*.txt"` as designating a second search root, in addition to `.`.  You presumably wanted to use `-name "*.txt"` to filter the find results; without it, `find` outputs the name of every file in the tree.  Presumably you're suppressing or ignoring the error messages that result.

But supposing that your subdirectories have no subdirectories of their own, as shown, and that you aren't concerned with dotfiles, even this corrected version ...

```
for f in `find . -name "*.txt"`;
```

... is an awfully heavyweight way of saying this ...

```
for f in *.txt;
```

... or even this ...

```
for f in *?myfile*.txt;
```

... the latter of which will avoid attempts to rename any files whose names do not, in fact, change.

Furthermore, launching a `sed` process for each file name is pretty wasteful and expensive when you could just use `bash's` built-in substitution feature:

```
    mv "$f" "${f/#*myfile/myfile}"
```

And you will find also that your working directory gets messed up.  The working directory is a characteristic of the overall shell environment, so it does not automatically reset on each loop iteration.  You'll need to handle that manually in some way.  `pushd` / `popd` would do that, as would running the outer loop's body in a subshell.

Overall, this will do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in $(find * -maxdepth 0 -type d); do
   pushd "$d"
   for f in *.txt; do
        mv "$f" "${f/#*myfile/myfile}"
   done
   popd
done
```

Comment: I was spoiled for choice of correct answers, but this one was so thorough and pointed out what I was doing wrong as well as some best practices. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without `find` and sed:

```
$ for f in */*.txt; do echo mv "$f" "${f/\/*myfile/\/myfile}"; done
mv subdir1/001myfile001A.txt subdir1/myfile001A.txt
mv subdir1/002myfile002A.txt subdir1/myfile002A.txt
mv subdir2/001myfile001B.txt subdir2/myfile001B.txt
mv subdir2/002myfile002B.txt subdir2/myfile002B.txt
```

If you remove the `echo`, it'll actually rename the files.

This uses [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to replace a slash and anything up to `myfile` with just a slash and `myfile`.

Notice that this breaks if there is more than one level of subdirectories. In that case, you could use extended [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) (enabled with `shopt -s extglob`) and the `globstar` shell option (`shopt -s globstar`):

```
$ for f in **/*.txt; do echo mv "$f" "${f/\/*([!\/])myfile/\/myfile}"; done
mv subdir1/001myfile001A.txt subdir1/myfile001A.txt
mv subdir1/002myfile002A.txt subdir1/myfile002A.txt
mv subdir1/subdir3/001myfile001A.txt subdir1/subdir3/myfile001A.txt
mv subdir1/subdir3/002myfile002A.txt subdir1/subdir3/myfile002A.txt
mv subdir2/001myfile001B.txt subdir2/myfile001B.txt
mv subdir2/002myfile002B.txt subdir2/myfile002B.txt
```

This uses the `*([!\/])` pattern ("zero or more characters that are not a forward slash"). The slash has to be escaped in the bracket expression because we're still inside of the *`pattern`* part of the `${parameter/pattern/string}` expansion.

Answer (score 1):

a slight modification should fix your problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in `find . -maxdepth 2 -name "*.txt"`; do
  mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed -r 's,[^/]+(myfile),\1,')"
done
```

note: this `sed` uses `,` instead of `/` as the delimiter.

however, there are much faster ways.

here is with the rename utility, available or easily installed wherever there is `bash` and `perl`:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name "*.txt" | rename 's,[^/]+(myfile),/$1,'
```

here are tests on 1000 files:

```
for `find`; do mv        9.176s
rename                   0.099s
```

that's 100x as fast.

John Bollinger's accepted answer is twice as fast as the OPs, but 50x as slow as this `rename` solution:

```
for|for|mv "$f" "${f//}"   4.316s
```

also, it won't work if there is a directory with too many items for a shell glob. likewise any answers that use `for f in *.txt` or `for f in */*.txt` or `find *` or `rename ... subdir*/*`. answers that begin with `find .`, on the other hand, will also work on directories with any number of items.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use the following command instead:

```
rename 's#(.*/).*(myfile.*)#$1$2#' subdir*/*
```

You can use `rename -n` ... to check the outcome without actually renaming anything.

**Regarding your actual question:**
The find command from the outer loop returns 3 (!) directories:

```
.
./subdir1
./subdir2
```

The unwanted `.` is the reason why all files end up in the parent directory (that is `.`). You can exclude `.` by using the option `-mindepth 1`.
Unfortunately, this was onyl the reason for the files landing in the wrong place, but not the only problem. *Since you already accepted one of the answers, there is no need to list them all*.